# Children don't re-render when parent component is optimised

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am seeing something that looks like a bug and have written a simple test case for it.

Please refer to this WebpackBin as it contains the test scenario:
http://www.webpackbin.com/EJpabsuJW

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. `children` is a `prop` and by not checking it in `shouldComponentUpdate` you are saying that you component update shouldn't depend on it

Comment: Hi, as much as it does make sense I suppose, how would you go about checking that the children have changed?

Also, although children is a prop I don't feel like it quite make sense for the parent to check its children?

Comment: Well, I suppose, you can't write such general-purpose component and redefine `shouldComponentUpdate` for it at the same time. `shouldComponentUpdate` is a hack, which you should use when you have real performance problem, so it's not assumed that you will define this method for all you components.

Comment: I do understand that you should only use `shouldComponentUpdate` when you have performance issues.

Obviously this example is trivial, but my real example is much more involved and I do have a real performance issue which is why i'm trying to optimise this in the first place.

I'm writing a grid component which has hundreds of components live updating.

Comment: By the way, if you are sure, that you use only immutable data structures, you can just compare you children by reference

Comment: I mean, you can just do `nextProps.children !== this.props.children`

Comment: How do you know React doesn't create a new instance at some point?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, if wouldn't work. Actually, children props are always different, so it will always call render function if you compare them

Comment: I guess the best thing you can do is define `shouldComponentUpdate` in you children component, which are only depend on your data `http://www.webpackbin.com/VyKP_huJb